# Using jQuery, how do I repeat a function in different intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the function to repeat after 8 seconds the first time and then again after 30 seconds. I have used setTimeout but not sure if this is the way to go about it.
Thank you.

Comment: Rest assured that it *is* the right way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a conjunction of `setTimeout` and `setInterval`:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    // this will run 8 seconds later

    window.setInterval(function() {
        // do here whatever you want to do at 30 seconds intervals
    }, 30000);    
}, 8000);
```

Comment: I don't think he needs it to repeat. every 30 seconds.

Comment: If he doesn't he could replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout`.

Comment: Sounds like he wants the same function to run too.

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout is perfect.

```
(function() {
    var func = function() {
        // Code here
    }
    setTimeout(func, 8000);
    setTimeout(func, 30000);
})();
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using `(...)();` here?

Comment: It just means that `func` doesn't pollute the global scope.

Comment: Love it! Thank you, it's short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript:

```
var interval = setInterval(yourFunction, 8000);
```

Where 8000 is the interval after which your function is executed again, and interval is a handle to the interval, in case you want to stop it using clearInterval